# Power BI Adobe Analytics connector is limiting dimensions

Tags: powerbi

I am using the Adobe Analytics connector for one of my reports. One of my 'Dimensions' is called 'Websites' and the data is a URL (www.myurl.com), we look at over 100 websites and I am looking at the traffic for each one. When I use the Websites dimension it only displays 10 of the sites out of the total number. Is there a way I can add a line of code in the advanced query editor to remove this limit? Or is this a limitation with the Power BI connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'Top parameter'(returns up to 50,000 dimensions per call) fixes my problem and breaks down my URL column by the correct number of dimensions as opposed to 10.

```
{Cube.ApplyParameter, "Top", {10000, "evar123"}},
```